# Share intent for file created using Android Storage Access Framework

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

Following the guidelines for API 30, I implemented the Android Storage Access Framework for when the user generated a file using my app. However now I am having trouble using the URI to further share the generated file using a share intent. I get the following error:

> java.lang.SecurityException: UID 10154 does not have permission to content:

From reading the documentation on SAF, I thought that if i created the file I would still have read access to the file the app created. But this is not what I am experiencing.

My app does the following:

- Opens a location chooser for saving the generated file using SAF
- Sends the URI for the file location to the main activity
- Main activity adds the URI to a share intent with the flag

> Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION

- When I start the activity, I get the security exception.

Everything was working using a FileProvider, but I guess you cannot use this for API 30 anymore. Any feedback/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Donny

Comment: "Sends the URI for the file location to the main activity" -- I do not know what you mean by that step, but you might be running into the problems that I outline in [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html).

Comment: Thank you for the blog link. You provide a good explanation why my approach does not work. URI permission is not persistent between activities in the same app.